# Apollo GraphQL, is there a way to manipulate the data that is being written to the cache during querying?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

According to Apollo GraphQL docs, Apollo Links can go in two directions - client -> server and server -> client:

[image: Apollo Link Control Flow]

However, I am not able to find docs or examples regarding links that go from server -> client. My goal is to catch and parse the incoming data that that is going to be stored in cache. This way, I can read a custom parsed data from cache. Is is possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can found after afterware example here:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/tree/master/packages/apollo-link-http#afterware-data-manipulation

Comment: Great! Thanks you for the help!